# How to replicate rows based on the values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

due a dataframe:

```
data={'a':'1',
      'b': '1,2,3',
      'c':'2'}

Out:    a    b    c
     0  1  1,2,3  2
```

I would like to replicate rows for each value in the column b:

```
Out:    a    b    c
     0  1    1    2
     1  1    2    2
     2  1    3    2
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `df.explode('b')`

Comment: What type of output do you expect when (for example) column C has values '1,2'?

Comment: I didnt think about that :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your column is a string of comma separated values as given, you can use:

```py
>>> data={'a':'1',
...       'b': '1,2,3',
...       'c':'2'}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([data])
>>> df['b'] = df['b'].str.split(',')
>>> df.explode('b')

out:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  2
0  1  2  2
0  1  3  2
```